# How to edit the generated Latex from word to my desire one?

Tags: word-to-latex, adjustwidth

This my first question in texSE and hope it will be a good experience like other SEs. Recently I have decided to write my thesis in LaTex, so I have to convert some previous written parts in word (specially using word equation tool) to latex. Well I tried many ways including Mathtype, GrindEQMath and Word-To-LaTex third party software where the latter worked. Now when I convert one of my formula using this software I get a LaTex file as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{surface}
\title{}
\usepackage[paperwidth=612pt,paperheight=792pt,top=72pt,right=72pt,bottom=72pt,left=72pt]{geometry}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{indentation}[3]%
    {\par\setlength{\parindent}{#3}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}       \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
    \advance\linewidth -\leftmargin       \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin%
    \advance\@totalleftmargin\leftmargin  \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
    \parshape 1\@totalleftmargin \linewidth\ignorespaces}{\par}%
\makeatother

% new LaTeX commands


\begin{document}


\begin{center}

\vspace{3pt} \noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{488pt}}
\parbox{488pt}{\raggedright

\[
{\left(\int{}{\chi{}}^*\hat{T}\chi{}ⅆ\tau{}\right)}_{\alpha{}}=\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{}\alpha{}}\int{}{\chi{}}^*\hat{T}\chi{}ⅆ\tau{}=-\frac{2\pi{}}{\mu{}}\left[-2\int_0^{\infty{}}rⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr+6a\int_0^{\infty{}}r^2ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-2a^2\int_0^{\infty{}}r^3ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr+16\beta{}\int_0^{\infty{}}r^3ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-8ab\int_0^{\infty{}}r^4ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-8b^2\int_0^{\infty{}}r^5ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr\right]
\]

} \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{2pt}

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

However when I open it in WindEdt and try to run using PDFTeXify, it returns some errors which I can't understand. Anyway it works by XeLaTeX but prints my formula badly shaped so that it overflows the width of the page.

My questions are:

1- Is there a better alternative to convert my equations from word equations to LaTex?

2- Can I just copy the part of equation in generated LaTex file and paste it in a new LaTex file? I tried to do so as follows

```
{\left(\int{}{\chi{}}^*\hat{T}\chi{}ⅆ\tau{}\right)}_{\alpha{}}=\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{}\alpha{}}\int{}{\chi{}}^*\hat{T}\chi{}ⅆ\tau{}=-\frac{2\pi{}}{\mu{}}\left[-2\int_0^{\infty{}}rⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr+6a\int_0^{\infty{}}r^2ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-2a^2\int_0^{\infty{}}r^3ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr+16\beta{}\int_0^{\infty{}}r^3ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-8ab\int_0^{\infty{}}r^4ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr-8b^2\int_0^{\infty{}}r^5ⅇ^{-2\alpha{}r-2\beta{}r^2}dr\right]
```

but I got errors, while I thought copying just the equation part doesn't need to recalling special package, Am I wrong? if Yes how can do this?

3- As I mentioned above, when I run the generated LaTex file using XeLaTex it works but prints the equation in one line and so long. How to correct it? I want to align it as following photo which is the original form of my equation in word
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  How should the output look like? Please add a sketch of the expected output to your question.

Comment: @leandriis Many Thanks. I just want to correct the generated code so that the equation is split to a few lines. At the moment it is printed in a single line and overflows the page

Comment: Where exactly do you want such a linebreak to occur, how are the individuel lines of youe equation supposed to be aligned...? Also, what kind of output do you expect from  `ⅆ` and `ⅇ`? Is the asterisk supposed to be a multiplication sign? A sketch would relly help clarify the expected output. Since you seem to have written this equation in word, why not share a screenshot of this equation in word?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, I added a screenshot. I would be grateful if you could tell me the general solution of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified code, using an `alignat*` environment and the `diffcoeff` package to simplify typesetting partial differentials:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{diffcoeff} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
     \left(\int \chi^*\widehat{T}\chi\,\mathrm{d}\tau\right)_{\!\alpha} & = & & \diffp*{\int \chi^*\widehat{T}\chi\,\mathrm{d}\tau}{\alpha} \\
     & = & & -\frac{2\pi}{\mu}\biggl[-2\int_0^{\mathrlap\infty}re^{-2\alpha r-2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r + 6a\int_0^{\mathrlap\infty}r^2e^{-2\alpha r - 2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r \\
     & & & -2a^2\int_0^{\mathrlap\infty}r^3e^{-2\alpha r - 2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r + 16\beta \int_0^{\mathrlap\infty}r^3e^{-2\alpha r -2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r \\
     & & & - 8ab\int_0^{\mathrlap\infty}r^4e^{-2\alpha r -2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r -8b^2\int_0^{\mathrlap\infty{}}r^5e^{-2\alpha r-2\beta r^2}\,\mathrm{d}r\biggr]
    \end{alignat*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, however it seems you have typed whole equation again yourself, while I wanted to use the generated code. Isn't there a method to edit generated code instead of writing new one? or I have to copy it part by part?

Comment: I didn't really type a new code. I removed a lot of unnecessary pairs `{}`  and added a few things, like the `alignat` environment or the `\widehat` command  in the place of `\hat`, because it looks better with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks, So I need to do the same every time I convert word equation to latex one? right? It seems a very time-consuming task! Any idea?

Comment: @Wisdom getting anything well marked up text out of word usually takes some hand correction it's the nature of the input. If it is just a one off conversion for your thesis then spending a few minutes cleaning up the conversion is worth it. If you are repeatedly batch converting thousands of equations, it's a different tradeoff, accept a "good enough" conversion and go with whatever the convertor generators. But for a thesis you could try different convertors, but basically they will likely all need some hand corrections.

Comment: Well, you have to determine which amsmath environment you need to obtain the layout you want and add what's necessary. Personally, I think it is faster to typeset directly in latex (all the more so as the code that word yielded contained unicode characters that basic latex cannot manage).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot David. You're right, it's a tradeoff. Anyway I have a lot of huge equations which unfortunately I have typed them in Word equation before. It was my fault which postponed writing in LaTex every time. However I must find the best way to convert the equations. Can you introduce me the best way?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, for real? you think so? maybe writing direct in Latex is a faster way!

Comment: I suggest you type a generic file for equations, to test  each equation to find the better layout. If there's something you can't do, you'll always find on this site a helpful hand, and, you'll learn quickly the ways to get what you want, I think.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot. How can I make a generic file while each equation differs from others and I have to detect the positions of line breaking in each one for example?

Comment: @Bernard can you tell me how to specify the equation number for your answer? just using `\tag{}`

Comment: You want a single number, I suppose? If that is the case, the simplest way uses a nested environment:  `\begin{equation}\begin{alignedat}{2}……\end{alignedat}\end{equation}`.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, a system for numbering the equations. Thanks

Comment: @Wisdom: Well, in the initial code I gave in my answer,  replacing `alignat*`  (unnumbered) with `alignat`, would number each line, which is meaningless here.  That's why I had to use the nested version `alignedat`. Another possibility (without alignment) would be to use the `multline` environment, which uses a single number, vertically centred. You can see details in the documentation of the `amsmath` package.